# How is the derivative of differential equation containing error function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, error-function

Consider,
$$c(x,t)= \exp\big(\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}\big)-\frac{x\pi^{1/2}}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\operatorname{erfc}\frac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}}$$
For calculating
$$\left|\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}\right|_{x=0}$$
how is the derivative of the above equation involving $\operatorname{erfc}$?

Comment: Given that $c(0,t)=1$, the obvious answer is “not at all”. Perhaps you misstated the question? Also, it is not clear to me what you really want to know. You do know the derivative of the error function, I suppose?

Comment: How do you interpret that $c(0,t)=1$? Since I couldn't solve it at x=0, I was checking if there is a tricky part connected with the derivative of the error function.

Comment: (Sorry, I've been out for a bit.) If you set $x=0$ in the formula for $c(x,t)$, *surely* you get $1$? But from the answer given, I gather that it's really about what happens when $x$ is small, but non-zero. That is a very different question than the one you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac d {du}\text{erfc}(u)=-\frac{2 e^{-u^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$ just apply the chain rule to get 
$$\frac d {dt}c(x,t)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } D x }{4 (D
   t)^{3/2}}\text{erfc}\left(-\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{D t}}\right)+\frac{x^2 }{2 D t^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 D t}}$$ Now, what happens when $x\to0$ ?

**Edit**

Just added for your curiosity : for small values of $x$, using Taylor you would get $$\frac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } D x}{4 (D t)^{3/2}}+\frac{3 x^2}{4 D t^2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Comment: This is exactly my confusion. In the book The Mathematics of Diffusion, p 33, this has been given as the solution. I wonder how it works at x=0.

Comment: Here, too, you get zero at $x=0$, for any given $t$. *However*, and this may be the source of your confusion, if you consider a limit in which both $x$ and $t$ approach zero, things can turn out different. Consider, for example, what happens if you let $x=At^{3/2}$ (for some constant $A$) and then let $t\to0$. **Added after a moment's thought:** In the sort of limit I indicated here, Taylor's formula doesn't actually give the right answer. (I think.) Caution is called for!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen. For sure, you are correct !